# Windows 10, IIS 10 and multiple

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

First question, can Windows 10 support multiple websites under IIS 10? If that is yes, the how?

We need them to be on the same port, 80, and to have SSO. We have tried setting the bindings to give each web site a hostname Any IP Address and port 80. Each has its own App Pool.

Do we need to get corporate IT involved to set up alias' in the corporate DNS server and Kerberos server?

Thanks,
Doug

@alex-kudryashev, thank you very much. I was doing fine until I hit adding the newly created certificate to IIS for my site. I went into Bindings, selected HTTPS and it asks for a Host Name, is that the hostname of the site or the fully qualified hostname? I created a SSL certificate but I do not see it in the choices for SSL certificate. Am I supposed to put the file in a special place? Also when creating the certificate do I use the hostname, fully qualified hostname or?? Also does the certificate have to be in a certain form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IIS10 on Windows 10 supports multiple sites. To create site

1. Open IIS management console, right click **Sites** and select *Add Site* then fill in *Basic Settings* (app pool, physical path, and others).
2. In *Binding* fill in *Host Name* field. Leave default values in IP and port settings.
3. Add line in **Hosts** file (`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`) `127.0.0.1 www.site.name`.
4. Create SSL Certificate (using OpenSSL) and assign it to https (port 443) in *Binding*.

Do the same for other sites.

Answer (score 1):

> I went into Bindings, selected HTTPS and it asks for a Host Name, is that the hostname of the site or the fully qualified hostname? I created a SSL certificate but I do not see it in the choices for SSL certificate. Am I supposed to put the file in a special place? Also when creating the certificate do I use the hostname, fully qualified hostname or?? Also does the certificate have to be in a certain form?

As far as I know, if you want to select special certificate for your IIS web application host binding.  You should firslty import the certificate.

I suggest you could follow below steps to import the certificate:

1.Open IIS managemnet console and find the certificate feature:

[image]

2.Select the import at right side:

[image]

3.Select the import certificate and type in the password.

Comment: Thanks, Brando. Still no go.

Comment: Could you please tell me details about why it doesn't work?

Comment: Even after importing the certificate I could not connect. What I did to get this to work was to delete the site in IIS and the create a new site making sure that the web site name matched the DNS name. After recreating everything worked fine.